# '=' symbol is not working in regex elasticsearch filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have scenario where I want to filter the data from index using the regular expression.

Data will be in form of sentences in a particular field.The data may also contains some special characters and '=' in it.

Below is the index details:

```
PUT / eventsdata {
"mappings": {
    "EventDataType": {
        "properties": {

            "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "std_with_spaces"
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "std_with_spaces"
            }
        }
    }
},
"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "std_with_spaces": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Below is the sample data available in my index:

```
id - 12
name - Java Application
description- Process (AppName=MyApplication) is not running in the system.
```

Below is my query which I am trying to run

```
GET /eventsdata/EventDataType/_search
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                        "regexp": {
                            "description": {
                                "value": ".*AppName=MyApplication.*"
                            }
                        }

                    }

        }
    }
}
```

But this is not giving any result.Below is the reference output

```
{
   "took": 19,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

If I remove the '=' symbol and filter with normal word(myapplication) is giving result.

Please help on this.

Comment: I'm curious, can you run `GET /eventsdata` and update your question with the results you get?

Comment: Updated the question with output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What mapping do you have for this index?

If field description is analyzed, then AppName=MyApplication is divided into tokens. 
If you treat description as not analyzed then this query would work. Or you can make a copy of this field (multifield) to be also indexed as not analyzed. Then search on it.

You can can read how to make multifield here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html